# Protecting against race conditions with context.Err()

Tags: go

As I understand it, when using contexts in Go, the proper way to check if the context was cancelled or hit a deadline is by calling context.Err() after the code in question. So something like:

```
func myFunc(ctx context.Context) {
    // call some context-aware functionality
    result, err := SomeContextAwareFunc(ctx)

    // check if we hit a deadline or cancellation
    if ctxErr := ctx.Err(); ctxErr != nil {
        // handle an expired and/or cancelled context here
    }

    // process the result
    _ = result
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, though, this represents a race condition.  It is possible that the context expires after SomeContextAwareFunc but before the Err function is called.  In that case, we would think the context expiration would have cut SomeContextAwareFunc short but it actually didn't (and, e.g., we could use the result).

I tested this in the playground with an artificial delay between the function returning and calling Err and it indeed incorrectly indicates an expired context.
https://play.golang.org/p/Rd-fhWOW-AB

What is the correct way to protect against this?  Must context-aware functions always return an error so that the caller only checks the context if an error is returned?

Comment: Any kind of timing check is inherently racy. You should call `Err` to get the error after you figure out something failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `SomeContextFunction` returns context errors or [wraps](https://godocs.io/errors#Unwrap) context errors, then use this code to determine if `SomeContextFunction` returned because of deadline or cancelation:

```
result, err := SomeContextAwareFunc(ctx)
if errors.Is(err, context.DeadlineExceeded) || errors.Is(err, context.Canceled) {
     // deadline exceeded or canceled
} else if err != nil {
     // some other eror
}
```

Because the deadline can expire or the context can be canceled after SomeContextAwareFunc returns, testing the error return from SomeContextAwareFunc is the only way to determine why the function failed.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of the point with my final question. It seems the context-aware function must return an error and that the error is all that matters (i.e. don't ever call context.Err() directly).  Is that really the way?

Comment: It appears so. I learned a bit about wrapped errors, too.  Thanks!